# PHP custom class and function autocompletion in TextMate project

Tags: php, autocomplete, textmate, textmatebundles

Is there a bundle which completes my custom classes and functions in a TextMate project?

Like the code hints with PHP core functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet it is possible to get auto completion for you custom classes. See my answer to this question : [Textmate autocompletion and class outline for PHP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781423/textmate-autocompletion-and-class-outline-for-php-project/3828448#3828448)

Comment: O that's nice! Now if someone could also implement argument hinting it would be great! (Will try to build that in myself)

Comment: Great keep me posted :) also static classes are handled really bad.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know (and tried to find out in the last couple of hours) there is no working possibility for code completing your own PHP classes and functions in TextMate.

On a sidenote: The PHP Code Completion bundle linked as an answer to this question is totally outdated. You should use the official PHP bundle from http://github.com/textmate instead. With this bundle you can at least complete PHP’s built-in functions, display documentation as a tooltip and load PHP’s docs for the selected function in a new window.

The only workaround (and it isn’t so nice compared to *real* code completion) is to know the TextMate shortcuts for fast navigation between and inside files:

- ⌘T (Go to File)
- ⇧⌘T (Go to Symbol)
- ⌃⌘T (Select Bundle Item)

It is also worth to look inside the PHP bundle in the Bundle Editor and memorize a couple of shortcuts. Once you learned a couple of them it’s as fast as with an IDE and code completion.

Answer (score 2):

Check out textmate php code completion here http://aralbalkan.com/822