# Textmate autocompletion and class outline for PHP project

Tags: php, autocomplete, textmate, textmatebundles, outline-view

I'm using PDT, but want to switch to any lightweit editor. First I want to try Textmate. Eclipse has several useful features:

- *class outlile* to get list of properties and methods (with signature) to navigate;
- *type hierarchy*, it is like *class outlile* but it shows full inheritance tree;
- autocompletion for custom classes names, methods etc. (not only for standard functions);
- *go to declaration* feature

Does Textmate provide this features, or is there bundles to get such functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it can be frightening — it was for me — but you can code very efficiently with Vim. It's definetly not a turnkey solution but if you have some time between projects it's worth it.

- [Taglist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) and [tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/) are plugins that provide code navigation.
- There are a number of [solutions](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=php%20completion&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) for autocompletion.
- you can go to declaration with `gd` in a single file or with exuberant ctags and `ctrl-]` in more complex situations.

Comment: @Anton Egorov I've switched to Vim a few months ago. The only reason why TM is still on my machine is because I've used it a couple of times to refresh my memory of menu entries names in order to answer some TM related questions here.

Answer (score 2):

You can get auto completion in TextMate for PHP using the [tm-completion](http://github.com/ciaran/tm-completion) bundle. In doesn't work anything as good as what you might see in other IDEs like Eclipse or Visual Studio, xCode. But is works.

Standard PHP completion is supported. See the PHP Bundle -> Support -> Help

Comment: I've recently seen the same plugin working for Ruby as well.

Answer (score 0):

TextMate has a 30 day trial, so give it a go and see how it is for you.

I use Coda, which has class outline and autocompletion for native PHP functions, but not custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

no, i don't think there's any of these - Textmate is a text editor, not a full-blown IDE.

default php bundle provides autocompletion and code hints... but only for built-in functions.

"go to symbol" command brings up class and functions outline... but only for the current file.

Answer (score 0):

For quickly browsing to classes, functions and methods in a file, there is the [TmCodeBrowser](https://web.archive.org/web/20210408114313/http://www.cocoabits.com/TmCodeBrowser/) plugin. It uses Exuberant CTags to index the various code types.